# Проблема с сериализацией на C++ CLR проект

Tags: c++-cli, сериализация

При разработке функции в приложение(WinForms) произошла проблема записи в файл. Мне нужно записать объект класса в файл, а для этого, как я понимаю, надо разрешить сериализацию класса(объекта). Попробовал написать перед определением класса атрибут
[Serializable] и [SerializableAttribute], но вылетает ошибка, что атрибут не определен.
Код заголовочного файла с определением класса:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//using namespace System;
//using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
//[SerializableAttribute]
//[ SerializableAttribute ]
public ref class Ingredient {
public:
    //bool is_there_one; //показатель - если ли он в рецепте
    double amount_gr; // количество в граммах
    System::String^ name; // название ингредиента
    
    Ingredient() {
        //this->is_there_one = false;
        this->amount_gr = 0;
        this->name = "";
    }
    Ingredient(System::String^ name, double count) {
        this->name = name;
        this->amount_gr = count;
    }
    ~Ingredient() {}
};
//[SerializableAttribute]
ref class Recipe {
public:
    Recipe() {}
    Recipe(System::String^ name, System::String^ instruction) {


    }
    System::Collections::Generic::List<Ingredient^>^ Ing_List = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<Ingredient^>();
    System::String^ name;
    System::String^ instruction;
};
```

Код обработчика нажатия, чтобы записать объект в файл:

```
private: System::Void button_OK_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        try {
            BinaryFormatter^ formatter = gcnew BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream^ stream = gcnew FileStream("test.bin", FileMode::OpenOrCreate);
            formatter->Serialize(stream, Current_Recipe);
            stream->Close();
        }
        catch (Exception^ e) { this->label_warning->Text = e->ToString(); }
    }
```